# Generate oracle database table from xml/xsd

Tags: xml, database, oracle, groovy, xsd

I need to generate oracle database table from xml/xsd file and populate it from those xml file in Groovy. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: show your xml file? have you tried any? what is your use case?

Comment: @Rao I have a many different custom xml files. I think is there solution to create universal solution or I need to handle each individually

Comment: you haven't given any useful info in OP and even after requesting it. It is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

There are solutions like [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) (active) or [apache ddl utils] (https://db.apache.org/ddlutils/) (dormant) which generate database DDL statements from XML. However there is predefined strict XML schema in which table definition needs to be specified.

Advantage is that, database object definitions are database agnostic (multiple db providers are supported out of the box). You can maintain your application supporting multiple databases just with one set of definitions.

If your XML and XSD are custom specifications, then you may end up writing a full custom solution.

If you are looking at just one database and a couple of ddl operations (like table, index, view creation), then its feasible, but if your scope is huge, then you will end up creating solution similar to any one of the above.